# SCTP client and server meets error when reading message sent by the other

Tags: c, linux, sockets, sctp

I'm implementing a simple SCTP client and server with Linux SCTP socket API. Client and server both use one-to-one socket style. After connecting to server, the client sends a hello message to server and the server responds back with its hello message. Here' the code for server and client:

server.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int srvr_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in clnt_addr;
    struct sctp_sndrcvinfo sndrcvinfo;
    struct sctp_event_subscribe event;
    socklen_t addr_sz;
    char snd_buf[] = "Hello from server";
    char rcv_buf[1024] = {0};
    int new_fd;
    int flags;
    int rd_sz;
    int ret;

    /* One-to-one style */
    /* Create socket */
    srvr_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
    if (srvr_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("Open srvr_sock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Bind to server address */
    memset(&srv_addr, 0, sizeof(srv_addr));
    srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT_NUM);
    srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP_ADDR_1);
    ret = bind(srvr_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr));
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        perror("Bind srvr_sock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Enable all events */
    event.sctp_data_io_event = 1;
    event.sctp_association_event = 1;
    event.sctp_address_event = 1;
    event.sctp_send_failure_event = 1;
    event.sctp_peer_error_event = 1;
    event.sctp_shutdown_event = 1;
    event.sctp_partial_delivery_event = 1;
    event.sctp_adaptation_layer_event = 1;
    if (setsockopt(srvr_sock, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_EVENTS, &event,
        sizeof(event)) != 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Listen */
    ret = listen(srvr_sock, 5);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        perror("Listen on srvr_sock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Server loop */
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for new connection...\n");
        new_fd = accept(srvr_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&clnt_addr, &addr_sz);
        if (new_fd < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to accept client connection");
            continue;
        }

        memset(rcv_buf, 0, sizeof(rcv_buf));
        rd_sz = sctp_recvmsg(new_fd, (void *)rcv_buf, sizeof(rcv_buf),
                            (struct sockaddr *) NULL,
                            0,
                            &sndrcvinfo,
                            &flags);
        if (rd_sz <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (flags & MSG_NOTIFICATION)
        {
            printf("Notification received. rd_sz=%d\n", rd_sz);
        }
        printf("New client connected\n");
        printf("Received %d bytes from client: %s\n", rd_sz, rcv_buf);

        /* Send hello to client */
        ret = sctp_sendmsg(new_fd, /* sd */
                           (void *) snd_buf, /* msg */
                           strlen(snd_buf), /* len */
                           NULL, /* to */
                           0, /* to len */
                           0, /* ppid */
                           0, /* flags */
                           STREAM_ID_1, /* stream_no */
                           0, /* TTL */
                           0 /* context */); 
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            perror("Error when send data to client");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Send %d bytes to client\n", ret);
        }

        if (close(new_fd) < 0)
        {
            perror("Close socket failed");
        }
    }
    close(srvr_sock);

    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int conn_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in srvr_addr;
    struct sctp_sndrcvinfo sndrcvinfo;
    socklen_t addr_sz = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int flags;
    char rcv_buf[1024] = {0};
    char snd_buf[] = "Hello from client";
    int rcv_cnt;
    int ret;

    /* One-to-one style */
    /* Create socket */
    conn_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
    if (conn_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Create socket conn_fd");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Specify the peer endpoint to which we'll connect */
    memset(&srvr_addr, 0, sizeof(srvr_addr));
    srvr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srvr_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT_NUM);
    srvr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP_ADDR_1);

    /* Connect */
    ret = connect(conn_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&srvr_addr, sizeof(srvr_addr));
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        perror("Connect failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Connected to server\n");

    /* Send hello to server */
    ret = sctp_sendmsg(conn_fd, (void *)snd_buf, strlen(snd_buf),
                        (struct sockaddr *) &srvr_addr, sizeof(srvr_addr), 0,
                        0, STREAM_ID_1, 0, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        perror("Send to server failed");
        close(conn_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Send %d bytes to server\n", ret);
    }

    /* Read message from server */
    rcv_cnt = sctp_recvmsg(conn_fd, (void *)rcv_buf, sizeof(rcv_buf),
            (struct sockaddr *) &srvr_addr, &addr_sz,
            &sndrcvinfo, &flags);
    if (rcv_cnt <= 0)
    {
        printf("Socket error or EOF\n");
    }
    else if (flags & MSG_NOTIFICATION)
    {
        printf("Notification received. rcv_cnt=%d\n", rcv_cnt);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Received %d bytes from server: %s\n", rcv_cnt, rcv_buf);
    }

    /* close socket */
    close(conn_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

common.h

```c
#define SERVER_PORT_NUM     16789
#define SERVER_IP_ADDR_1    "192.168.56.102"
#define STREAM_ID_1         1
```

Client and server are running on 2 Debian VMs in the same subnet, client's IP is 192.168.56.101, server's IP is 192.168.56.102.

When I start the server and then run the client, most of the time the client fails with following output:

```
./client
Connected to server
Send to server failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

However the server shows that it has read data sent from client and has responded with server hello message:

```
 ./server
Waiting for new connection...
Notification received. rd_sz=20
New client connected
Received 20 bytes from client: ▒
Send 17 bytes to client
Waiting for new connection...
```

Also the data received from client is corrupted in this case.

I tried to run the client many times and sometimes it succeeds:

```
$ ./client
Connected to server
Send 17 bytes to server
Received 17 bytes from server: Hello from server
```

The server still shows same log messages in this case.

Why would the client fail most of the time while only succeed a few times? The result seems to be unpredictable to me. Also why the data read by server is corrupted in server's output?

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind also client socket.
In client.c between socket create and before connect put:

```
cli_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
cli_addr.sin_port = 0;
cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY); /* or inet_addr("192.168.56.101"); 
for multiple ip addresses or network cards */
ret = bind(conn_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));
if (ret < 0)
{
  perror("Bind client_sock");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```